# Webpack: Clean up chunks - but only chunks

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am using the chunking-feature of webpack (`^5.44.0`) to create chunks. This works fine, but I mentioned that there are lots of chunks created over days

```sh
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff   135K Jul 14 14:24 home-view.7a174a95c4b6c5db7d16.js
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff   135K Jul 21 16:35 home-view.883b7079d7003f7aa412.js
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff   135K Jul 21 16:36 home-view.8e332e11ef50c41b6e9e.js
#redacted for better readability...
```

This is the `webpack.mix.js` (as I am using Laravel-mix):

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /node_modules(?:\/|\\).+\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'],
                    babelrc: false
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
});

mix.js("resources/js/main.js", "public/js").vue();

mix.extract(['vue']);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix
        .version();
}
```

If I extend this to

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js'
        clean: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /node_modules(?:\/|\\).+\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'],
                    babelrc: false
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
});

mix.js("resources/js/main.js", "public/js").vue();

mix.extract(['vue']);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix
        .version();
}
```

all content in the `public` directory is wiped away, even those files I need:

```
public
├── css
│   └── app.css
├── favicon.ico
├── fonts
│   ├── ...
├── index.php
├── js
│   ├── chunks
│   │   ...
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── manifest.js
│   └── vendor.js
├── mix-manifest.json
├── robots.txt
├── storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public
└── web.config
```

But I really just want webpack to clean up everything stored in `./chunks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack output clean method mainly designed to clean whole output folder. However since you are using it with Laravel (i am not familiar with it) some important files are mixed in your public folder. I see two ways to solve this problem.

First option is you can put your webpack assets to other folder in `public` then webpack will clean only this `assets` folder:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
  clean: true,
}
```

The other options is to put all your important files under `static` folder and then just exclude this path from cleaning:

```
output: {
  clean: {
    keep(filePath) {
      return filePath.includes('static');
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just keep everything that doesn't contain js/chunks using regex;
try:

```
output: {
   clean: {
      keep: /^(?!.*js\/chunks.*$).*
   }
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/62cRgG/1